# Caching images on a subdomain after installing Nginx on a dedicated server

Tags: caching, nginx, cpanel, dedicated-server

I installed the Nginx on a dedicated server using the below codes:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nginxcp.com/latest/nginxadmin.tar 
tar xf nginxadmin.tar
cd publicnginx
./nginxinstaller install
```

Nginx service status is `up` in Nginx Admin panel in WHM (please see the below image).
[image: Nginx admin status]

Below is also the configuration file as in Configuration Editor:

```
user  nobody;
# no need for more workers in the proxy mode
worker_processes  2;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20480;
events {
 worker_connections 5120; # increase for busier servers
 use epoll; # you should use epoll here for Linux kernels 2.6.x
}
http {
 server_name_in_redirect off;
 server_names_hash_max_size 10240;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;
 include    mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 server_tokens off;
# remove/commentout disable_symlinks if_not_owner;if you get Permission denied error
# disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout  5;
 gzip on;
 gzip_vary on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_http_version 1.0;
 gzip_min_length  1000;
 gzip_comp_level  6;
 gzip_buffers  16 8k;
# You can remove image/png image/x-icon image/gif image/jpeg if you have slow CPU
 gzip_types    text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/xml application/javascript application/xml+rss text/javascript application/atom+xml;
 ignore_invalid_headers on;
 client_header_timeout  3m;
 client_body_timeout 3m;
 send_timeout     3m;
 reset_timedout_connection on;
 connection_pool_size  256;
 client_header_buffer_size 256k;
 large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
 client_max_body_size 200M; 
 client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 request_pool_size  32k;
 output_buffers   4 32k;
 postpone_output  1460;
 proxy_temp_path  /tmp/nginx_proxy/;
 proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:5m max_size=1000m;
 client_body_in_file_only on;
 log_format bytes_log "$msec $bytes_sent .";
 log_format custom_microcache '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" nocache:$no_cache';
include "/etc/nginx/vhosts/*";
}
```

My images are located in `http://images.domain.com`, so my question is how to add the Nginx proxy cache configuration that can cache the images on my images sub-domain for two hours?

Answer (score 0):

By nginx static files are serves perfectly. 
My configuration for images.domain.com.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name images.domain.com;
    set $path       /home/images.domain.com;
    set $webroot    $path/public_html;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|tar|wav|bmp|wmv|avi|3gp|mp3|mp4|css|js|ico)$ {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/imgages.domain.com.log main;
            root $webroot;
            expires 2h;
    }
}
```